# Error BC30002 only at runtime with HigLabo

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to use HigLabo mail objects (System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient as problems with SSL/TLS) to send mails from a VB.NET application.

I've added the dlls references to my project and I'm able to use the HigLabo.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient class sending mails when I run the code within Visual Studio.

I'm getting a strange BC30002 (Type not defined) error, instead, when I call my aspx outside VS, even from the web server itself.

These are the debug lines:

```
BC30002: Tipo 'HigLabo.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient' non definito.

Riga 45:     Private Sub SendEmail(text As String)
Riga 46: 
Riga 47:         Dim smtpClient As New HigLabo.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient   <--- Error here
Riga 48:         smtpClient.ServerName = "smtp.gmail.com"
Riga 49:         smtpClient.Port = 587
File di origine: C:\...\EmailEditor.aspx.vb    Riga: 47
```

Can you please help me to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Antonio

Comment: so it works in visual studio, but not when you install it on a webserver?

Comment: The situation is even more simple,  I don't really install the application elsewhere, the website home directory is the source code folder itself,  the one I deal with in VS.